# Integrating Yammer Feed on SharePoint online (O365 Multi-tenant)

Tags: yammer, office365-apps

I'm working on a SharePoint online (O365 Multi-tenant) environment and trying to integrate Yammer feed into the SharePoint site. SharePoint sites are authenticated to the users thru their AD account(/credentials) while Yammer credentials are not (Yammer username is same as the user's email address in AD but the password is different). This scenario is not allowing me to perform single-sign on. Hence, I've resorted to have a service account that will always be used pull the yammer feed on the SharePoint site, irrespective of the user logged in to the SharePoint site.

From my study and understanding so far, embedding yammer script is not really a viable option in my case (because it would always present the login button to the user or take the cached yammer credentials from the browser). My objective is to by pass this for users when they view the SharePoint page, but when they post or reply to yammer network from the SharePoint site feed, they should not be challenged for credentials (or at the least should enter credentials only once). I'm trying to achieve this thru provider hosted SharePoint app. Any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve this?